# TypeError: list object is not an iterator

Tags: python, flask

Am trying to make a simple post api in flask-python but am getting this error :

```
TypeError: list object is not an iterator
```

but when i revise my code seems fine what could be the problem.

My function which specifically has the problem:

```
def post(self,name):
        #return {'message': name}
        item = next(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, items), None)
        if item:
            return {'message':"An item with name '{}' already exixts. ".format(name)},400
        data = request.get_json()
        item = {'name': name, 'price':data['price']}
        items.append(item)
        return item, 201
```

When i try to post something on **postman** i get this `logcat` **error**:

```
[2018-06-07 10:41:02,849] ERROR in app: Exception on /item/test [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\flask_workspace\MealBookingApp\MealBookingApp\MealBookingApp\views.py", line 30, in post
    item = next(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, items), None)
TypeError: list object is not an iterator
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2018 10:41:02] "POST /item/test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**NB:**

***line 30*** , is the line below :

```
item = next(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, items), None)
```

Comment: You seem to be running Python 3 code on Python 2.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try using `iter()`

**Ex:**

```
item = next(iter(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, items)), None)
```

Answer (score 20):

To elaborate on @Rakesh's answer, lists aren't iterators, and the output of `filter()` in Python 2 is a list. To fix this, you can use the `iter()` function to output an iterator corresponding to the problematic list so that `next()` can be called appropriately. The same code then should solve your problem:

```
item = next(iter(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, items)), None)
```

Note that using `iter()` on an iterator still works in Python 3, so this code is forward compatible.

Comment: you could add that using `iter` on an iterator also works so the code is also compatible with python 3.

Comment: You can also use a list comprehension to save a filter call: item = next(iter([i for i in items if i['name'] == name], None))